# ActiveX control in conflict with ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, arcgis-9.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with ArcToolbox tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15565/problem-with-arctoolbox-tools)

In arcgis 9.1 (in both OS, XP SP3 and 7 ultimate 64bit) when I open Arctoolbox appears a message that it is impossible to open eevry tools (but the Arcgis works for every other performance), because there is a conflict with web browser (?) and control ActiveX. I think there is a problem in/with Windows register, but I am not be able to make changes. I have ask help to ESRI Italy and ESRI US, but with no solutions. Anyone have had the same problem?